# Does the Mono C API support unicode filepaths/identifiers?

Tags: c, winapi, unicode, mono

So I'm working on Windows-specific project that utilizes the Mono C API, and up until now, have been using wide-character strings (`wchar_t*`) for everything. (mostly for the sake of supporting file paths longer that 260 characters) I'm running into a roadblock, however, as it appears the Mono app domain API doesn't support loading assemblies from a UTF16 file path.

The API I'd normally use is [mono_domain_assembly_open](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=xhtml%3Adeploy%2Fmono-api-domains.html#api:mono_domain_assembly_open), but there doesn't seem to be any alternative API that takes the `name` parameter as a `const wchar_t*` or `MonoString*`.

Looking ahead a bit, I'm also wondering how one would access classes/methods in a loaded assembly when the class/method name contains non-ANSI characters. (since .NET identifiers can contain any valid Unicode character) API like [mono_method_desc_new](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=xhtml%3Adeploy%2Fmono-api-methods.html) only have `char` based implementations.

I'm aware that I can use [WideCharToMultiByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) to remap the strings, but am unsure on what codepage to use in order to ensure proper functionality if the user's filepath or identifier names contain non-ANSI characters.

Comment: Just because they only have a multibyte interface doesn't necessarily mean they can't support unicode. UTF-8 can encode the full unicode space in a multibyte string. You'd need to check the documentation to see if that's supported.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I can find nothing in the [documentation](http://docs.go-mono.com) that describes the supported encoding(s) for `char*` strings. UTF-8 would be a good bet, though

Comment: .NET assemblies use [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) for their metadata. UTF-8 is the default encoding for characters. When you encounter an API that takes a `char*`, try UTF-8.